# How to reload table of one view from other view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios6

I am trying to reload table of MyView.m from MySliderController.m but its not reloading.
i have declared below method in MyView.m

```
 -(void)updateData{
      [self.itablview reloadData];
 }
```

and calling that method form MySliderController.m class by below code

```
 DDMenuController *menuController = (DDMenuController*)((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).DDmenuController;
MyView *obj = [[MyView alloc]init];

if(indexPath.row == 3){
    [menuController showRootController:YES];
    [obj updateData];
}
```

that method gets called but table is not reloading even i am checking existence of tableview by below code

```
-(void)reloadtable:(id) sender{
    NSlog(@"%@",self.itableview)
    [self.itableView reloadData];
}
```

in console i get (null)

but when i am checking in below code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"%@", self.itableView);
}
```

i am getting below message . it means table exists

```
2013-06-29 19:31:48.673 slidingViews[7025:c07] <UITableView: 0x79d9400; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x714e940>; layer = <CALayer: 0x714e3f0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

what can be the issue. Please check my code here 
https://github.com/kanwarpalSingh/mycode
```

Comment: `MyView *obj = [[MyView alloc]init];` creates  a new instance, and I guess, you want to load the table of `existing` instance.

Comment: are these two different screens? if so just do it in view will appear...

Comment: yes.. you can also check my code at https://github.com/kanwarpalSingh/mycode

Comment: @AnoopVaidya .. if i am trying to reload existing instance table. then y its accepting didselectrowatindexpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you're instantiating the `MyView` you're actually creating a new (but not visible) version of the MyView view controller, not the original `MyView` you originated from. There are a few different methods to handle this and it really comes down to what works best for you.

One example would be to subscribe `MyView` to a custom notification originating from `MySliderControl` such as this...

MyView.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateData:) name:@"updateDataOnMyView" object:nil];
}
```

MySliderControl.m

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateDataOnMyView" object:nil];
```

You can also use a delegate method if you don't like this setup. There are plenty of tutorials out there on creating your own delegates as well. Good luck!